# Where can I find a list of numpy functions which release the GIL?

Tags: python, numpy, gil

I have found several SO questions asking about this in one way or another, but none of them actually either give a list or refer to one.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200437/numpy-and-global-interpreter-lock) refers to [a wiki page](http://wiki.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming), but while the wiki page talks *about* the GIL and multi-threading, it doesn't give a list of GIL releasing functions.

[This mailing list post](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-May/025399.html) indicates that the only way to find out is to read the numpy source. Really?

Answer (score 3):

It's not guaranteed to catch everything, but I just ran:

```
git grep nogil
```

in my clone of the numpy repository. It turns up 82 usages in 2 files:

- `random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx`
- `random/mtrand/numpy.pxd`

Comment: The C thing for releasing the GIL is Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS, if you want to look for that too.

Comment: This answer basically is "read the source." Is that really the only option?

Comment: Numpy is an open-source project... If you're feeling philanthropic, you could add this information to the [documentation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/doc) and submit a pull request, so no one else has to read the source!

Comment: Actually numpy has its own macros for releasing the GIL, they are defined [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L931). Grepping for `THREADS` should cover all of the cases.

Comment: @Jaime beware that linking to a code line in GitHub means that your link stops making sense when the code changes and the line numbered in the link is no longer the same code you originally wanted to point to. It's better to link to a code line *within a specific commit* so that it can't ever change.