# Parallel programming array handling in Python

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing

I have seen a number of questions on using python's `multiprocessing` but I have not been able to quite wrap my head around on how to use this on my code.

Suppose I have a NxM array. I have a function `f` that compares the value at (i,j) to every other pixel. So, in essence, I compute NxM values at every point on the grid.

My machine has four cores. I envision that I would split the input locations in four quadrants and then feed each quadrant to a different process.

So, schemetically, my current code would be:

```
def f(x, array):
    """
    For input location x, do some operation 
    with every other array value. As a simple example,
    this could be the product of array[x] with all other
    array values
    """
    return array[x]*array

if __name__ == '__main__':
    array = some_array
    for x in range(array.size):
        returnval = f(x,array)
```

`

What would be the best strategy in optimizing a problem like this using multiprocessing?

Comment: How do you want to store the answers? In another array?

Comment: If your problem are mathemathical you may want to look at `numpy`. Despite being bound to a single-core performance by GIL in CPython, numpy code releases it so your code can be even more effective with threading+numpy than with multiprocessing.

Comment: @bbayles yes, it would have to be another array of the same size, NxM. Retaining the order is thus important.

Comment: @myaut could you elaborate on how numpy specifically would help me here? In addition, as I understand it threading is particularly useful for I/O, not so much for heavy calculations?
Thanks!

Comment: @John: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200437/numpy-and-global-interpreter-lock

Answer (score 1):

The [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library can do most of the heavy lifting for you, with its Pool.map function.

The only limitation is that will use a function that takes a single argument, the value you are iterating. Based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments), the final implementation would be.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

# Make a version of f that only takes x parameter
partial_f = partial(f, array=SOME_ARRAY)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=5)  # Number of CPUs + 1
    returnval = pool.map(partial_f, range(array.size))
```

Answer (score 0):

The strategy you've described - send the data set to several workers, have each compute values for part of the data set, and stitch them together at the end - is the classical way to parallelize computation for an algorithm like this where answers don't depend on each other. This is what [MapReduce](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce.html) does.

That said, **introducing parallelism makes programs harder to understand, and harder to adapt or improve later.** Both the algorithm you've described, and the use of raw Python for large numerical computations, might be better things to change first.

Consider checking whether expressing your calculation with `numpy` arrays makes it run faster, and whether you can find or develop a more efficient algorithm for the problem you're trying to solve, before parallelizing your code.