# Why are numpy calculations not affected by the global interpreter lock?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing, gil

I'm trying to decide if I should use multiprocessing or threading, and I've learned some interesting bits about the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). In this nice [blog post](http://nathangrigg.net/2015/04/python-threading-vs-processes/), it seems multithreading isn't suitable for busy tasks. However, I also learned that some functionality, such as I/O or numpy, is unaffected by the GIL.

Can anyone explain why, and how I can find out if my (probably quite numpy-heavy) code is going to be suitable for multithreading?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*Many* numpy calculations are unaffected by the GIL, but not all.

While in code that does not require the Python interpreter (e.g. C libraries) it is possible to specifically release the GIL - allowing other code that depends on the interpreter to continue running. In the Numpy C codebase the macros `NPY_BEGIN_THREADS` and `NPY_END_THREADS` are used to delimit blocks of code that permit GIL release. You can see these in [this search of the numpy source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=NPY_BEGIN_THREADS).

The [NumPy C API documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#threading-support) has more information on threading support. Note the additional macros `NPY_BEGIN_THREADS_DESCR`, `NPY_END_THREADS_DESCR` and `NPY_BEGIN_THREADS_THRESHOLDED` which handle conditional GIL release, dependent on array `dtypes` and the size of loops.

Most core functions release the GIL - for example [Universal Functions (ufunc)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) do so [as described](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.code-explanations.html#function-call):

> as long as no object arrays are involved, the Python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) is released prior to calling the loops. It is re-acquired if necessary to handle error conditions.

With regard to your own code, the [source code for NumPy is available](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy). Check the functions you use (and the functions they call) for the above macros. Note also that the performance benefit is heavily dependent on *how long* the GIL is released - if your code is constantly dropping in/out of Python you won't see much of an improvement.

The other option is to just test it. However, bear in mind that functions using the conditional GIL macros may exhibit different behaviour with small and large arrays. A test with a small dataset may therefore not be an accurate representation of performance for  a larger task.

There is some additional information on parallel processing with numpy available [on the official wiki](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/ParallelProgramming.html) and a useful post about the Python GIL in general [over on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/186909/162315).